# jquery fadeIn or fadeOut

Tags: jquery

Here i'm trying to blink (fadeIn/fadeOut) link and on hover, mouseOn - blink should stop and mouseOut should again start blinking. It works in case of div but not on a link.
Please suggest am going somewhere wrong.
Thanks in advance !

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myclass" ><a class="myBlink">Click here!</a></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myclass a").fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500, fadeContent);  // this is not working
```

Comment: and your jQuery code?

Comment: what you want to as output ? please tell clearly

Comment: please share the code that you used to blink `div`

Comment: Why to use CAPS in tag?

Comment: Post your jQuery code

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with fadein and fade out? You don't make it blink with those two effects. You can make a function with intervals that hides and shows your link on mouse hover using jquery and css. But the question isn't very clear. If you want ot make it fade in and fade out use css transitions rather than jquery.

Comment: @user28470 , thats wat i said, and OP didnt respond yet

Comment: sorry for some reason i'm unable to post my script here which i'm working.  it's giving error while i submit

Comment: You should read guidelines [How to Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?

Comment: $(".myclass a").fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500, fadeContent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` is a block level element and `a` anchor is an inline element. Try to make it a block level element by adding style on it as given below:

```
<div class="myclass" >
    <a class="myBlink" style="display: block;">Click here!</a>
</div>
```

Hope it will work. Thanks!